# How to query a list of objects from a Rails API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, http

I am trying to query a list of objects from a Rails API. That is, let's say I'd like to get the instances with id `2`, `4` and `7` from a certain model.

My closest guess so far has been passing a comma-separated string of `id`s to a regular `resource/:id` route, then I split the param, built an array from it and passed it to a `where` call.

It works - however, I feel like this is not a clean way of doing what I am aiming to do.

So I'm asking you if there's a *Rails way* of handling this.

How should the URL look like? How do I read the passed values from the controller?

Comment: Is this an API under your control? If you want to pass array parameters to a Rack application (like Rails) you would pass them through as `?foo[]=1&foo[]=2&foo[]=3`. Which will give you `{ foo: [1,2,3] }`. Handling this in the show method is not right though. This should be done in the index method as you're displaying multiple records with a filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it should be a filter on index path accepting `ids` param.

So URL should look like

```
/resource?ids[]=2&ids[]=4&ids[]=7
```

And you can find those resources with

```rb
def index
  if params[:ids].blank?
    @resources = Resource.all
  else
    @resources = Resource.find(params[:ids])
  end
end
```